# Rhythmbox build error

Tags: development, rhythmbox, software-sources, install-from-source

I'm trying to build Rhythmbox in order to fix a bug, but am running into problems doing so.

I downloaded the source using `sudo apt-get source rhythmbox` afterwhich I ran `configure` with the argument `--prefix=/home/notgary/rhythmbox/build` in order to keep the compiled binary from messing up my existing system. After running `make` and `make install`, which successfully placed a binary at `/home/notgary/rhythmbox/build/bin/rhythmbox`, I tried to run the program and got the output that can be seen below.

I've got little experience with building Linux programs from source so am at a loss to figure out why this is happening. Does anyone know how I can get a compiled binary of Rhythmbox (or any other app from the repositories for that matter) up and running?

```
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.rhythmbox' is not installed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.rhythmbox.rhythmdb' is not installed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.rhythmbox.podcast' is not installed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_key_info: assertion `settings->priv->schema != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.rhythmbox.player' is not installed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.rhythmbox' is not installed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_key_info: assertion `settings->priv->schema != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion `g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_key_info: assertion `settings->priv->schema != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion `g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_double: assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_DOUBLE)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_key_info: assertion `settings->priv->schema != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion `g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_double: assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_DOUBLE)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_key_info: assertion `settings->priv->schema != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_string: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): Rhythmbox-CRITICAL **: rb_play_order_new: assertion `porder_name != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): Rhythmbox-CRITICAL **: rb_play_order_playing_source_changed: assertion `RB_IS_PLAY_ORDER (porder)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_key_info: assertion `settings->priv->schema != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion `g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get_key_info: assertion `settings->priv->schema != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_string: assertion `value != NULL' failed
(rhythmbox:27863): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_unref: assertion `value != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error trace output gives a clue about this:

```
GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.rhythmbox' is not installed
```

The application is looking for gconf(dconf?) database settings that dont exist.

It is likely you either need to install the repository version of rhythmbox, or possibly force the reinstallation to ensure the schema values are created.

i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```

or

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install rhythmbox
```

Once rhythmbox and its associated schemas are correctly setup - any alternative version should also be able to run.