# Building Rhythmbox from source

Tags: rhythmbox, development, gstreamer

I'm trying to build rhythmbox from source to have a go at adding an extra feature. I'm running into issues with `gstreamer`

```
configure: error: Package requirements (    gstreamer-1.0 >= 0.11.92
gstreamer-audio-1.0 >= 0.11.92
gstreamer-base-1.0 >= 0.11.92
gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0 >= 0.11.92
gstreamer-pbutils-1.0 >= 0.11.92) were not met:

No package 'gstreamer-audio-1.0' found 
No package 'gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0' found
No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
```

I've tried what's in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104566/rhythmbox-build-error),

```
sudo apt-get build-dep rhythmbox
```

and installing some of the gstreamer packages to no avail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you need to install the devel packages of gstreamer. Try installing these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

Comment: I just edited the version on your answer to match my error. It works with the 1.0-dev package

Comment: I had the same problem with Berasero v3.8 and this soled the problem.